# How to use different weights for different input samples for regression with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

**What I want to do:** I have multiple parallel time series and I'm trying to predict another value based on all of these time series (I'm not sure if this is still called regression).
One of these time series is the most important one, its values should have a higher influence than the values from the other time series.

**What I did:** I have a neural network implemented with the keras functional API. It has several Inputs, one for every time series:

```
main_input = Input(...)
context_input1 = Input(...)
context_input2 = Input(...)
...
context_inputn = Input(...)
```

**Where is the problem:** How can I achieve that the samples in *main_input* have a higher influence than the samples in *context_input1, ... , context_inputn*? I know you can do something like this when you are using the network for classification (and therefore have different classes in your data):

```
model.fit(x=..., y=..., sample_weight={class1=0.6, class2=0.4}
```

How can I achieve different sample weights when i do not have different classes but different Inputs in my training data?

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done. NN will find the optimal weights to approximate loss function as much as possible.

Imagine that you have two inputs `inp1 = [1.]` and `inp2 = [1.]` and `labels = [1.]`; your model is `a * inp1 + b * inp2` and loss is `mse`. As a result of training `a` will probably be ~ 0.5, and `b` ~ 0.5 (or `a` ~ 0.1, `b` ~ 0.9). It is impossible to add your weights here.

But you can establish limits over `a`, `b` if needed. If, for example, you need `a` to be as small as possible - then you can add another loss.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing keras `class_weights` with `sample_weights`

`sample_weights` is used to provide a weight for each training sample. That means that you should pass a 1D array with the same number of elements as your training samples (indicating the weight for each of those samples). In case you are using temporal data you may instead pass a 2D array, enabling you to give weight to each timestep of each sample.